# Regular expression for capturing hashtags in groups

Tags: ios, regex

I need a regular expression to capture a #hashtag in multiple groups(group 1-"#" group 2-"hasshtag").
I tried:

```
"(\\b#)([a-z0-9]{1,})(\\b)"
```

But this doesn't capture anything.Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be: `"(\\B#)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"`

Comment: Try `"\\B(#)(\\w+)"`. Please also add the code to repro into the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
"(\\B#)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"
```

`\B` asserts position where `\b` does not match. Using `\b` before `#` will fail the match unless there is a word character before `#`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ej3BvC/1)